# How to resolve MediaType dynamically in Jersey

Tags: jersey, multipartform-data, dropwizard

My application supports file download. In my storage I have variety of file types, and in my download method I don't know which one of them my client will demand. So, I'm searching for annotation(s) which will allow Jersey to dynamically resolve mediaType that it produces.

How to configure a method to return such a result using jersey or any other annotations?

EDIT

I decided to use `applicaion/octet-stream` as I didn't find anything else usefull

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers your question, but have you considered setting the media type in the `Response` class? There are a few methods to do that.

Comment: I decided to use octet-stream as a response, setting it in a response object is to much work on resolving file type for me

Comment: That's what I would suggest, `application/octet-stream` will do the job. There's another alternative you may consider if you are willing to use external dependencies. [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) works really well when resolving the media type of files, but use lots of dependencies.

Comment: Other options available in Java SE are [`Files.probeContentType(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) and [`MimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html#getContentType-java.io.File-).

Comment: You also could consider [`URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName-java.lang.String-) and
[`URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream-java.io.InputStream-).